# In a C header file I saw `[*]` used as array bound. What does this mean?

Tags: c, arrays

In one of our files I saw this function

```
void match(int states[*]);
```

I have never seen such a thing in C. Can someone please explain that what this weird operator in the brackets mean?

Comment: Be careful to stay away from managed code, makes perfect sense there.

Comment: This is usually easier when the OP goes "oops, that might be it".

Comment: @Hans, ain't that the truth...

Comment: @Hans my code is managed by subversion.

Comment: I don't think that's what he meant by [managed code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code).

Answer (score 9):

This is syntax that was new in C99.  It is valid only for a parameter in a function declaration that is not also a definition.  It indicates a variable-length array of unspecified length; in this case, since it is at the top level, it is (as usual) completely equivalent to `int states[]` and `int *states`.

This syntax is useful if a pointer to an array is passed - for example, if we have a function like:

```
void foo(size_t n, int a[][n])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

..then we can write a compatible declaration that provides a prototype as either:

```
void foo(size_t n, int a[][n]);
```

or as:

```
void foo(size_t, int a[][*]);
```

These are completely equivalent.

(By the way, the `*` there is not an operator, it is just punctuation.)

Answer (score 5):

`[*]` denotes a C99 variable-length array of unspecified size, which is only valid in prototypes, but nevertheless a complete type (ie distinct from `[]`, which denotes an incomplete array type).

Your example, however, makes no sense. A more reasonable example would be

```
// in header file:
void match(size_t, int *[*]);

// in source file:
void match(size_t count, int *states[count])
{
    // ...
}
```

As the parameter names are omitted, the array declaration can't refer to the first argument, so a placeholder had to be introduced.

However, as parameter adjustments still get applied, the prototype is identical to

```
void match(size_t, int **);
```

and the array type information is discarded.

This is not the case for higher indices of multi-dimensional arrays, eg

```
double det(size_t rows, size_t cols, double mat[rows][cols]);
```

only discards the `rows`, ie the declaration is equivalent to

```
double det(size_t rows, size_t cols, double mat[][cols]);
```

and

```
double det(size_t rows, size_t cols, double (*mat)[cols]);
```

which in turn correspond to the following compatible declarations

```
double det(size_t, size_t, double [*][*]);
double det(size_t, size_t, double [][*]);
double det(size_t, size_t, double (*)[*]);
```

To prevent the parameter adjustment, pass a pointer to the array instead, ie

```
double det(size_t rows, size_t cols, double (*mat)[rows][cols])
```

Then, `sizeof *mat` should return the expected value within the function body.

Comment: bad example because the determinant is only defined for square matrices - hopefully, at least the code makes sense ;)

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. I see now that there is no way to write `double[*][*][*]` without the `[*]` because we cannot write `[1]` at a non-toplevel position (it would make the type incompatible with the parameter type in the definition) and we cannot write `[]` because array types cannot have another array type without a size as element type. Is this correct?

Comment: @litb: yes, this is indeed correct; in particular, the type of array elements must be complete (ie have a known size), even if its size is not known until runtime in case of VLAs

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You *can* still write `double [*][*][*]` without the `[*]`, but doing so requires you to name the parameters in the prototype (you must do `sometype n, double [n][n][n]` or equivalent).

Comment: @caf: And most importantly, there's no way to use named arguments in prototypes in a namespace-safe manner.

Comment: @R.. can you please explain? I haven't yet used namespaces in C. Why will it be unsafe?

Comment: C does not have namespaces; that's the whole point. You can't name arguments without reserving for your header's use a name which otherwise could be used by the surrounding code as a preprocessor macro. Thus if you use named arguments, you're forced to document a huge number of additional reserved names with your header, or else name them all with some pattern (like `mylibname_arg_pathname` instead of `pathname`, which gets really ugly in a hurry...)

Comment: R..: I don't think this is a common problem: most naming conventions upper-case object-like macro names and lower-case parameter names, which makes clashes impossible

Comment: @R.. don't those names have function prototype scope rather than file scope? Thus I am in the impression that `int a; void f(int a);` is fine, even though both identifiers called `a` are in the same ordinary identifier namespace, but in different scopes. If I'm missing something can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If I understand him correctly, he means that if you have `void foo(int maxsz)` then you can't have `#define maxsz 1024` valid at the same time. Very rarely a real problem, not sure I've ever encountered though I've use named parameters for ~15 years.

Comment: You rarely encounter it with your own code. It's much more often a problem with other people's libraries or other people's code calling your libraries. One common example is code that's been made reentrant/multi-instance by using `#define` to replace all the old static variables (usually short lowercase names) `foo` with `context->foo`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)-ism for specifying a variable length array in a prototype.  See §6.7.5.2 (para.4 in particular).  (I don't think I've ever seen anything use it before!)